# Powershell Exchange 2010 on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-8, ironpython

The Follow script worked fine under win 7 with no issues, but when I loaded my app on windows 8 to see what all was broken I found that this script would no longer work correctly. Its a very simple script to load up user exchange Mailbox for searching if the user has a mailbox within a larger app. It's actually written in python because I use IronPython as a plugin system.

```
    password = SecureString()
    str_password = "PASSWORD"
    str_user = "EXCHUSER"
    uri = "http://" + exchangeServerIP + "/PowerShell"

    for c in str_password:
        password.AppendChar(c)

    creds = PSCredential(str_user, password)

    connectionInfo = WSManConnectionInfo(Uri(uri), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", creds)

    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic

    runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)

    runspace.Open()

    powershell = PowerShell.Create()
    powershell.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox")
    if self.txtUsername.Text != "*":
        powershell.AddParameter("Identity", self.txtUsername.Text)

    powershell.AddParameter("ResultSize", "Unlimited")
    powershell.Runspace = runspace

    results = powershell.Invoke()

    if results == None or results.Count <= 0:
        MessageBox.Show("No mailboxes can be found!")
        runspace.Close()
        runspace.Dispose()
        powershell.Dispose()
        return

    self.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    for result in results:
    >>>>>>> if result.Properties != None:   (ERROR HERE)  <<<<<<<
                if result.Properties["Name"] != None:
                    if result.Properties["Name"].Value != None:
                        System.Console.WriteLine(result.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString())

    runspace.Dispose()
    runspace.Close()
    runspace = None

    powershell.Dispose()
    powershell = None

    connectionInfo = None
```

I have marked where I get the error saying the result.Properties is NoneType which when debugging I can see that it is populated and the correct results are there. Not sure if windows 8 / .net 4.5 is the cause of the issue but works fine under win 7 exact code no null value. Any Suggestions would help greatly.

**Updated (Answer):**

After constant digging I finally found that the issue was with Powershell 3. Access the Members on using Powershell 2 with IronPython I could use result.Members["Name"].Value but with Powershell 3 and the DLR, IronPython will return null value on result.Members Collection so I have to call it as result.Name. (Where result = PSObject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know what error you are getting during compilation of ur above code.

Also

1.First check whether your code sdk version matches with your current software version.

2.The code/app which are developed using visual studio 2008/09/10/11 wont work in visual studio 2012.

3.If you copied the windows 7 app files to compile it in win8,it wont work.just create/code it from first in vs 2012.